# Why does an implementation with C arrays outperform eigen in this case?

Tags: c++, eigen3, economics

A relatively well known set of benchmarks for coding languages in Economics is that produced by  S. Borağan Aruoba and Jesús Fernández-Villaverde, the code for which may be found [here](https://github.com/jesusfv/Comparison-Programming-Languages-Economics). For C++ there are two implementations to solve the stochastic neoclassical growth model, one using C style arrays and the other using C++ STL arrays. Recently I've been practicing my C++ as I am starting to work on some large-scale models for which the language is likely to be useful (although I expect to work primarily in Julia) and decided create a variant of this code using the Eigen library as I am relatively unfamiliar with its use. Interestingly my code using Eigen is significantly slower than either of the two C++ programs in the above link. My assumption is that this is due to a combination of my implementation being poor and this problem being too simple for Eigen to be worth using due to it increasing overhead, however I would like to ask whether this assumption is correct?

My code using eigen is:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Timer Start
    const auto time_0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Parameter Declaration
    const double aalpha = 0.33333333333;     // Elasticity of output w.r.t. capital
    const double bbeta = 0.95;              // Discount factor;

    const size_t nGridProductivity = 5;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, nGridProductivity, 1> vProductivity;
    vProductivity << 0.9792, 0.9896, 1.0000, 1.0106, 1.0212;

    Eigen::Matrix<double, nGridProductivity, nGridProductivity> mTransition;
    mTransition << 0.9727, 0.0273, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
                   0.0041, 0.9806, 0.0153, 0.0000, 0.0000,
                   0.0000, 0.0082, 0.9837, 0.0082, 0.0000,
                   0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0153, 0.9806, 0.0041,
                   0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0273, 0.9727;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Steady State
    const double capitalSteadyState = std::pow(aalpha * bbeta, 1. / (1. - aalpha));
    const double outputSteadyState = std::pow(capitalSteadyState, aalpha);
    const double consumptionSteadyState = outputSteadyState - capitalSteadyState;

    std::cout << "Output = " << outputSteadyState << ", Capital = " << capitalSteadyState << ", Consumption = " << consumptionSteadyState << "\n";
    std::cout << " ";


    // Capital Grid
    const int nGridCapital = 17820;
    
    Eigen::VectorXd vGridCapital(nGridCapital);
    vGridCapital.setLinSpaced(nGridCapital, 0.5 * capitalSteadyState, 1.5 * capitalSteadyState); 
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Required Matrices and Vectors

    Eigen::MatrixXd mOutput(nGridCapital, nGridProductivity);
    Eigen::MatrixXd mValueFunction (nGridCapital, nGridProductivity);
    mValueFunction.setZero();//Need to initialise to zero for first iteration
    Eigen::MatrixXd mValueFunctionNew(nGridCapital, nGridProductivity);
    mValueFunctionNew.setZero();
    Eigen::MatrixXd mPolicyFunction(nGridCapital, nGridProductivity);
    mPolicyFunction.setZero();
    Eigen::MatrixXd expectedValueFunction(nGridCapital, nGridProductivity);


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Pre-Build Output
    mOutput = (vGridCapital.array().pow(aalpha).matrix()) * vProductivity.transpose();
    std::cout << "Test mOutput" << mOutput(2, 2) << std::endl;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Main Iteration

    const double tolerance = 0.0000001;
    double maxDifference = 10.0;
    std::size_t iteration = 0;

    while (maxDifference > tolerance)
    {
        expectedValueFunction = mValueFunction * mTransition.transpose();

        for (std::size_t nProductivity = 0; nProductivity < nGridProductivity; ++nProductivity)
        {
            // We start from previous choice (monotonicity of policy function)
            std::size_t gridCapitalNextPeriod = 0;
            for (std::size_t nCapital = 0; nCapital < nGridCapital; ++nCapital)
            {
                double valueHighSoFar = -100000.0;
                double capitalChoice = vGridCapital(0);

                for (std::size_t nCapitalNextPeriod = gridCapitalNextPeriod; nCapitalNextPeriod < nGridCapital; ++nCapitalNextPeriod)
                {
                    const double consumption = mOutput(nCapital, nProductivity) - vGridCapital(nCapitalNextPeriod);
                    const double valueProvisional = (1. - bbeta) * std::log(consumption) + bbeta * expectedValueFunction(nCapitalNextPeriod, nProductivity);
                    if (valueProvisional > valueHighSoFar)
                    {
                        valueHighSoFar = valueProvisional;
                        capitalChoice = vGridCapital(nCapitalNextPeriod);
                        gridCapitalNextPeriod = nCapitalNextPeriod;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mValueFunctionNew(nCapital, nProductivity) = valueHighSoFar;
                        mPolicyFunction(nCapital, nProductivity) = capitalChoice;
                        // We break when we have achieved the max (note: of a monotonic function)
                        break;
                    }
                    mValueFunctionNew(nCapital, nProductivity) = valueHighSoFar;
                    mPolicyFunction(nCapital, nProductivity) = capitalChoice;
                }
            }
        }


        maxDifference = (mValueFunctionNew - mValueFunction).cwiseAbs().maxCoeff();
        mValueFunction = mValueFunctionNew;

        ++iteration;
        if ((iteration % 10 == 0) || (iteration == 1))
            std::cout << "Iteration = " << iteration << ", Sup Diff = " << maxDifference << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Iteration = " << iteration << ", Sup Diff = " << maxDifference << "\n";
    endl(std::cout);
    std::cout << "My check = " << mPolicyFunction(999, 2) << "\n";
    endl(std::cout);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Timer End
    const auto time_1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    const auto elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(time_1 - time_0).count();
    std::cout << "Elapsed time is   = " << elapsed_seconds << " seconds." << std::endl;
    endl(std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```

Which is essentially a direct copy of the above linked code with C arrays / STL arrays replaced by eigen matrices. It is in need of some tidying and more comments but is hopefully still readable.

On my system the check values are:

C array version : 0.146549

STL array version: 0.146549

Eigen version: 0.146552 - This is concerning but close enough that as far as I can tell the implementation works

The measured times are:

C array version :  0.609375

STL array version: 0.635014

Eigen version: 0.938192

with very little variance between runs of the program.

These were compiled with the Visual C cl compiler using the settings mentioned in the above linked github (`cl /F 4000000 /o testvcpp /O2 RBC_CPP.cpp`).

Comment: Just hazarding a guess here, but it seems your algorithm is using element-wise operations (as in indexing the matrices/vectors). My guess is the library optimized block operations (vector/matrix multiplication and the like). Usually changing elements when you want to make block operations fast involving changing extra data you wouldn't need to if you were just dealing with regular arrays.

Comment: You could try compiling with assertions disabled (should be `/NDEBUG` with MSVC) -- after ensuring that your code runs correctly. But MSVC sometimes still has problems with inlining some Eigen methods, so if you can't switch to clang or gcc, you may have to live with some overhead.